# How to show/hide DOM element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

There are button (id= "hide_message_button") and message(id="message"). The click on the button should hide/show the message. The source code:

```
$('#hide_message_button').click(function(){
   var bool = $('#message').css('visibility','hidden').is(':hidden');
   if(bool){
      $('#message').show();
      $(this).val('Hide');
   }
   else {
      $('#message').hide();
      $(this).val('Show');
   }
});
```

I have a bug: the message is hidden with first click on the button and didn't shown again (but button's value is changed to 'Show'). What's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#hide_message_button').click(function(){
    $('#message').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Elements with `visibility: hidden` style properties are *not* hidden, since they occupy space in layout. Try:

```
var bool = $('#message').is(":hidden");
```

or:

```
var bool = $('#message:hidden').length;
```

or:

```
var bool = $('#message').css("display") == "none";
```

From the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/):

> Elements can be considered hidden for several reasons:
>
> - They have a CSS display value of none.
> - They are form elements with type="hidden".
> - Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
> - An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the    page.

Comment: thanks! I tried all three options and all three ones work absolutely right. It is very interesting solution with "length".

Answer (score 2):

That's because the `css('visibility','hidden')` call is hiding the message, and then it's never shown again because the `show` method doesn't change the `visibility` style.

The element will then toggle between being hidden (display=block, visibility=hidden) and being removed (display=none, visibility=hidden). In one state the element takes up space, but the message is not shown in either state.

Just remove the code that sets the `visibility` style, and the code works.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/JqE3Y/

Comment: I think that the bool has also true value because the button's value changes with each click from "Show" to "Hide" and viceversa. I also tested it with alert message that I put in the "if" block.

Comment: @tatiana_c: Yes, it does, actually. I already updated my answer with a more accurate description, and a corrected code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the demo and the answer. It works and it's great.

Answer (score 1):

Use toggle instead of verify visibility. This code works: http://jsfiddle.net/8qu9y/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function.

```
<input type="button" id="hide_message_button" value="My button" />
<p id="message">A message</p>​
```

and

```
$('#hide_message_button').click(function(){
   $('#message').toggle();
});​
```

Comment: I don't see why the button also disappear if you just toggled the `#message` id...

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wrote before something different. This code works fine. Thanks.